# Equally spacing all the views inside TabWidget android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a tabWidget defined as:

```
<TabWidget
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_without_bg"
    />
```

Now I am adding custom ImageViews in it:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabbar_button_home);
ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
img1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
img1.setImageDrawable(d);

TabHost.TabSpec tSpecHome = tHost.newTabSpec("timeline");
tSpecHome.setIndicator(img1);
tSpecHome.setContent(new MyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
tHost.addTab(tSpecHome);
```

The problem with this code is that all the images are spaced with each other in middle. 
e.g `abcdef`

I want them to stretch to full width and have space in between them e.g `a   b  c  d  e`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the code as follows:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabbar_button_home);
ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
img1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f)); // this line changed
img1.setImageDrawable(d);
```

**Explanation:**

The third parameter in the `LayoutParams` constructor is the `weight`. Each image view now has a weight of `1.0f`. So they will spread across the layout.

Comment: Just one addition, LayoutParams must be of type linearlayout. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You have them with `WRAP_CONTENT` width.

Instead they should be set to a width of `0dp` and each one have a layout gravity of 1.